# Windows API createprocess returning 2 for getlasterror

Tags: c++

I am getting the getlasterror set to 2 for createprocess.
The code is as below:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string cmd = "\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_66\\bin\\java.exe\"";
    std::string param = " com.server.serv %*";
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    std::cout << cmd.c_str();
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
int result = CreateProcess((LPCTSTR)cmd.c_str()  ,   // No module name (use command line)
            _T(" -cp com.ge.med.terra.eat.server.EATServer %*" ),       // Command line
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi);
        if(result == 0)
        {

            DWORD dw = GetLastError();
            std::cout << dw;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I checked the path for java.exe and its correct, can someone please point me what I am doing wrong.
I dont want to execute using cmd.exe /C.

Comment: Remove quotes in `cmd` string

Comment: I tried taht, it did not work.

Comment: And the path to the command is actually correct? If you try it in e.g. a command window it works fine?

Comment: yes I tried it in command window and its working fine.

Comment: Oh, and `UNICODE` is not defined?

Comment: @Sneha Did you, at least, tried looking for the [meaning of the error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: The cast in `(LPCTSTR)cmd.c_str()` should be unnecessary and suggests that you're building for Unicode and should use `std::wstring` (or an array of `TCHAR`, which is simpler).

Comment: @Algirdas yes it means path mentioned is not correct.

Comment: CreateProcess() is quite quirky.  If you use the 1st argument then you have to repeat it in the 2nd.  If you don't then whatever program you start is going to get very confused about its argv[] argument.  Just easier to pass NULL as the 1st.  ShellExecuteEx() is a lot less painful.  And never cast a string to shutup the compiler, use std::wstring or CreateProcessA().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does ::CreateProcess(path,cmd,...) fail with error "File not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447528/why-does-createprocesspath-cmd-fail-with-error-file-not-found)